# Load order of objects in Python pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I have a python pickle file and when I try to load it, I would like it to load one specific object before another (because I have some dependencies...).

Is that possible?

Here is the scenario:

```
class A:

  def __init__(self):
       self.known_names = ["Dan", "David"]

  def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name not in self.known_names:
           raise UnknownName
        else:
           return self[name]

class B:
   def __init__(self):
       self.a_instance = A()
   def __setattr__(self, name, value):
       if self.a_instance.attr == "something":
          do_something...
   def __setstate__(self):
        self.foo = "blah"
```

The problem occurs when loading the pickle file. class B instance is loaded beofe class A. In that scenario, class B's `__setstate__` method tries to set `self.foo`. This results `__settattr__` method call which checks `self.a_instance`'s `attr` attribute. However, class A was not unpickled yet so `self.known_names` does not exist. So calling the `__getattr__` of A's results in an infinite recursion (since `known_names` does not exist, it calls `__getattr__` on it as well).

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#subclassing-unpicklers

Answer (score 0):

This is not a dependency problem per se since normally `__init__` will not be called when unpickling an object.

As described in the [Python pickle docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances) and [this ticket](http://bugs.python.org/issue5370) your problem is most likely that `A` cannot be safely unpickled due to the use of `__getattr__`.

Implementing `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` in `A` might be sufficient:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    """Extract state to pickle."""
    return self.__dict__

def __setstate__(self, d):
    """Restore from pickled state."""
    self.__dict__.update(d)
```